# Create edge descriptor without graph

Tags: c++, boost

In my project I use one file that stores all edges; and another stores edge probabilities. I want to use `Boost` library for graph and `unordered_map` for probabilities. I have the following code.

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list <boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS> DiGraph;
typedef boost::graph_traits<SubGraph>::vertex_descriptor vertex_t;
typedef boost::graph_traits<SubGraph>::edge_descriptor edge_t;

unordered_map<edge_t, double> P;

ifstream infile(prob_filename);
double p;
int u, v;
while (infile >> u >> v >> p) {
    P[make_pair(u, v)] = p;
}
```

However, I don't need to make a pair as a key, but an edge descriptor `edge_t`. How can I create edge descriptor with given two values *u* and *v*.

Answer (score 0):

[From boost graph concepts](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/graph_concepts.html)

```
DirectedGraph digraph(V);
  {
    boost::graph_traits<DirectedGraph>::vertex_descriptor u, v;
    u = vertex(0, digraph); // read these instead 0,1 from from your file
    v = vertex(1, digraph);
    // populate graph
    add_edge(digraph, u, v, Weight(1.2)); // read weight (prob) instead from from your file

    boost::graph_traits<DirectedGraph>::edge_descriptor e;
    bool found;
    boost::tie(e, found) = edge(u, v, digraph);

    //use property map
    property_map<DirectedGraph, edge_weight_t>::type
      weight = get(edge_weight, digraph);

    cout << "weight[(u,v)] = " << get(weight, e) << endl;

  }
```